# Why isn't "this is about business finance" in the list of reasons to vote to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Working through the list of votes to close today, I kept coming across questions that were really about business finance, not personal.

Yet there seemed to be no appropriate category to select for the reason for voting to close. In each case, an earlier close voter had to write in their own reasons for voting to close.

It looks like whowever drew up the list of reasons missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can often use "Questions about accounting are off-topic". But in general the number of close reasons we can set are limited so we have to be selective.

I guess maybe we could merge the first two into "Questions about economics or accounting are off-topic unless...".

Comment: That still seems to omit professional finance ("business finance") which would largely be more appropriate under quantitative finance -- since most of finance is now "quantitative" if we go by definitions from when the term was first used.

Comment: @kurtosis The reason to merge Accounting and Economics would be to allow a new category to be added for business finance, I believe.

Comment: @Joe Ah, sensible. Thanks for pointing that out!